# Tooltipster maxWidth setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

Could someone please help me. I'm looking for a solution for setting a `maxwidth` on a Tooltipster tooltip bubble. I'm not talking about the area which activates the tooltip, I'm talking about the tooltip bubble itself. When I put a few sentences of text in a tooltip it stretches from the left to the right of my screen and sometimes goes off the page. I want to be able to set a max width at say 400px, where anything in excess would be broken onto a new line.

[tooltipster-maxwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5p0C.png)

I already checked and tried changing this in the javascript file:

maxWidth
Set a maximum width for the tooltip. Default: null (no max width)

But nothing happened. It still appears like it does in the screenshot. Could it be because I've applied it to a paragraph tag? I tried to apply it to a span tag instead but it did the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

The `maxWidth` option that's given with Tooltipster is one that needs to be passed into the `tooltipster()` function when you initialise the tooltip itself, i.e.

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    // Other setup goes in here as key:value pairs
    'maxWidth': 500   
});
```

From the example above, this will "restrict" your tooltips to occupy a max width of 500 pixels. I've setup a very simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zupeq5L1/1/) showing various examples with custom `maxWidth` options which  should help you out with the syntax.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir! The code you mentioned above looks a little bit different to mine, but I still managed to get this to work:


`;(function ($, window, document) {
 var pluginName = "tooltipster",
  defaults = {
   maxWidth: 500,
  };`

Comment: I actually already tried this before but forgot I was using the minified JS doh! :)

Comment: I was just about to say that looks like minified code ;) No problems, well it's always here for future reference :D